# HTML error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Tags: javascript, html

Borrowing some HTML code from another source. The point of the code is to create a randomized grammar deck, giving you a random example from the list each time. I have dabbled in basic html but this is a bit beyond me. I'd appreciate any pointers!

This is the error message:
"Invalid HTML on card: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null"

Here is the code.
Front Template:

```
<div class="example" id="ex1">
  <span class="jp">{{ex1_jp}}</span><br />
  <span class="jp">{{ex1_en}}</span></div>
<div class="example" id="ex1">
  <span class="jp">{{ex2_jp}}</span><br />
  <span class="jp">{{ex2_en}}</span></div>
<script>
  var exFields = 2;
  var exCount = 0;
  for(var i=1;i<=exFields;i++){
    var divid = "ex"+i;
    var divText =document.getElementById(divid).innerText.trim();
    if(divText!=""){
      exCount += 1;}
    else{break;}};
  var x = Math.floor(exCount*Math.random())+1;
  var divToShowId = "ex"+x;
  divToShow = document.getElementById(divToShowId);
  divToShow.style.display = 'block';
  var clozeElements = document.getElementsByClassName("cloze");
  for(var j=0;j<clozeElements.length;j++){
    var charCount = clozeElements[j].innerText.length;
    var circleString = "";
    for (var k=0;k<charCount;k++){
      circleString += "◯";}
    clozeElements[j].innerText = circleString;}
</script>
```

Styling:

```
.cloze {
color:blue;}
.example .en{
visibility:hidden;}
.jp:hover ~ .en{
visibility:visible;}
```

Back Template:

```
<div id=grammar>
  <span class="jp">{{grammarPoint}}</span></div>
<div id=usage>
  <span class="en">{{explanation}}</span></div>
<br />
<span class="jp">―例文―</span>
<div id="ex1" class="example">
  <span class="jp">{{ex1_jp}}</span><br / >
  <span class="en">{{ex1_en}}</span></div>
<div id="ex2" class="example">
  <span class="jp">{{ex2_jp}}</span><br / >
  <span class="en">{{ex2_en}}</span></div>
<script>
  var exFields = 2;
  var exCount = 0;
  for(var i=1;i<=exFields;i++){
    var divid = "ex"+i;
    var divText =document.getElementById(divid).innerText.trim();
    if(divText!=""){
      exCount += 1;}
    else{
      document.getElementById(divid).style.display = "none";}};
</script>
```

Comment: Your first code snippet repeats `id="ex1"`: this is invalid HTML.

Comment: The issue is here `document.getElementById(divid).innerText.trim()`. If no element can be found by executing `document.getElementById(divid)`, then the result will be `undefined` and `undefined` won't have a property called `innerText`, hence your error.

Answer (score 0):

You have got two **EX1**

use this code

```html
<div class="example" id="ex1">
  <span class="jp">{{ex1_jp}}</span><br />
  <span class="jp">{{ex1_en}}</span></div>
<div class="example" id="ex2">
  <span class="jp">{{ex2_jp}}</span><br />
  <span class="jp">{{ex2_en}}</span></div>
```